# square icon display without filling the place holder space in tablets

Tags: codenameone

I have 512 x 512 image as icon for the application. This icon display in optimized way in iphones and android phones. I see issue on bigger screens like iPads and Android Tabs where icon is not streached to fill the place holderand instead this squre image display at the center and top and bottom fill with gap. Please advise if anyone encounter similar thing.

Thanks

Comment: The icons are always square. Can you provide a screenshot?